# Create new file type, add checksum and data from compressed file?

Tags: java, file, checksum, file-type

I have a txt file which i compressed with an algorithm, and have calculated a MD5 checksum for the original txt file. Now i have to create a new file type (new extension) and add the compressed data and the checksum. After decompressing the new file type i need to check if the checksum matches with the original file.

My question is:
What is the best way to create the new file type and add the data and checksum?

I was thinking about the following method:
Write the checksum first into the new file (as plain txt) and then write the compressed data after that. When reading the file i read checksum first, dont close the InputStream and continue with reading the compressed data. Is this a good way to do it?

Any links or solution are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: New file type can be simple and only 1 file will be compressed at a time

Comment: Please avoid asking for opinions on this forum.  "What is the best way", "What do you prefer", "How would you do this", etc., belong in other forums.  This forum is specifically for you to post the code you've tried, along with the research you've already done, and ask for help fixing it.  I'm not saying your question is invalid - just that it doesn't belong on this forum.

Comment: Your biggest consideration is the size of the compressed file. If the compressed file is still fairly large (1/2+ MB) I'd just use JSON or XML to encode the checksum & data fields. If you feel like this file type should be the absolute SMALLEST it can be, I would suggest allocating the first x bytes of data... 4 would be an int, 6 would be a long, but you might need more... the size of this field should be the MAXIMUM you could ever imagine your file size being.

Comment: @Stan I may have asked my question the wrong way. I did provide a solution to my problem and wanted to see if doing it that way is viable. I didnt provide any code snippet, but its just 2 loops where the first reads checksum, i dont close the stream and start the 2nd loop that reads the compressed data.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thank you for the answer, these arent big files and im using Arithmetic coding. So ill use your 2nd suggestion. EDIT: how do i mark this answer as resolved?

Comment: Again, I'm not arguing the validity of your question - I'm just pointing out that it is somewhat out of step with this forum's guidelines.

Comment: I understand, im new to posting questions. Usually i find an answer by searching, i just couldnt find anything this time.

Comment: @SafetOkic I've added my comment as an answer. You can click on the check to mark it as accepted and the question closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest consideration is the size of the compressed file. If the compressed file is still fairly large (1/2+ MB) I'd just use JSON or XML to encode the checksum & data fields. If you feel like this file type should be the absolute SMALLEST it can be, I would suggest allocating the first x bytes of data... 4 would be an int, 6 would be a long, but you might need more... the size of this field should be the MAXIMUM you could ever imagine your file size being